# How do i load a text file into this program?

Tags: java, input

How do i go about loading a text file into a java program that i have posted below. I have tried but am out of luck, any help will be appreciated!

Thank you.

```
  import java.io.*;


    public class test1 {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            if (args.length != 1) {
                System.out.println("usage: Tut16_ReadText filename");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            try {
                FileReader infile = new FileReader(args[0]);
                BufferedReader inbuf = new BufferedReader(infile);
                String str;
                int totalwords = 0, totalchar = 0;
                while ((str = inbuf.readLine()) != null) {
                    String words[] = str.split(" ");
                    totalwords += words.length;
                    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                        totalchar += words[j].length();
                    }
                }

                double density = (1.0 * totalchar) / totalwords;
                if (totalchar > 0) {
                    System.out.print(args[0] + " : " + density + " : ");
                    if (density > 6.0) 
                        System.out.println("heavy");
                    else
                        System.out.println("light");
                } else
                    System.out.println("This is an error - denisty of zero.");
                infile.close();
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                System.out.println("This is an error - execution caught.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might help you [How to read file in Java – BufferedReader](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/). Anyway if you explain whats currently happening then it will be useful for others to understand your problem.

Comment: Posting the error message or other details about why it's not working as you expect would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an easier way to read files. From Java 7 the `Files` and `Paths` classes can be used like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("usage: Tut16_ReadText filename");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]));

    for (String line : lines) {
        // Do stuff...
    }

    // More stuff

}
```

Then, in order to start the program and get it to read a file that you specify you must provide an argument when starting the app. You pass that argument after the class name on the command prompt like this:

> $ java Tut16_ReadText /some/path/someFile.txt

This passes "/some/path/someFile.txt" to the program and then the program will try to read that file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running java 8 it is a breeze with the new io streams. Advantage is on large file all text is not read into memory.

```
public void ReadFile(String filePath){

    File txtFile = new File(filePath);

    if (txtFile.exists()) {

        System.out.println("reading file");

        try (Stream<String> filtered = Files.
                lines(txtFile.toPath()).
                filter(s -> s.contains("2006]"))) {//you can leave this out, but is handy to do some pre filtering

            filtered.forEach(s -> handleLine(s));
                        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }
}

private void handleLine(String lineText) {

    System.out.println(lineText);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
while(s.hasNext()){..}
```